# Правильная работа с SQLite-базой в Android

Tags: sqlite3, android, java, база-данных

Есть готовая БД, лежащая в assets, которая копируется в папку приложения (ну, как обычно, в `/data/data/app_name/databases`). Создание и копирование происходит во внешнем (обычном `new Thread()`) потоке при старте приложения. За идею взята эта статья: 
[линк](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/).

У многих пользователей появляются разные ошибки при старте приложения, а у других все работает. Сдается мне, что описанный подход распространения готовой БД ошибочен, либо содержит неточности, которые нужно знать. Как вариант, есть мысль хранить данные не в базе, а в файле, который при возникновении ошибок снова парсится и заполняется база в методе `onCreate()` `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Как вы решаете перенос готовой базы в приложение? Как работаете со своей БД?

Есть куча туториалов и все как один создают структуру БД в `onCreate()`, делают апдейт в `onUpgrade()`, но готовая база распространяется в основном, как описано по ссылке.

Ошибки, возникающие при таком подходе (из статьи по ссылке):

- No such table android_metadata. Правда автор статьи это исправил созданием этой таблице в готовой БД, но подход сомнителен, ибо система сама создает эту таблицу в каждой базе.
- Теперь вот поймал ошибку такую: [Issues](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=949).
- На некоторых девайсах было, что при открытом коннекте после вызова `getReadableDataBase()` валится приложение (например, на HTC Desire).

Comment: Посмотрите. Может полезно будет. 
http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/125883/

Comment: Спасибо:))))) Это мой пост:)))))

Comment: Чорт :) Я так и думал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильная работа с БД в Android - это наследование SQLiteOpenHelper и переопределение методов onCreate и onUpgrade. В первом мы создаем базу данных. Например, можем распарсить данные и создать бд. Во втором мы обновляем базу, удаляя ею старую версию. Когда мы получаем объект БД и в дальнейшем вызываем getReadableDatabase()/ getWritableDatabase() вызывается наш метод onCreate() и если база не создана, она будет создана вновь. Можно также переопределить и эти методы. Но обычно так не делается. Все выше изложенное из моей практики.

Comment: это конечно всё хорошо, но часто парсинг может занимать очень много времени и разумнее было бы копировать БД из апка. Тем более как показала практика, этот способ также рабочий

Comment: как раз таки не очень то и рабочий. Разные девайсы - разные результаты. Поток копирования прирвется или GC вмешается - потеряете часть данных или БД вообще целиком, что кстати и бывало. Лучше не отходить от предложенной изначально практики.

Способ то рабочий, но с большими косяками. В любом случае, ничто не мешает использовать их оба.

Answer (score 0):

No such table при неправильном копировании файла таблицы. Если вы сравните начальный и конечный файлы - то их размеры вроде бы совпадают, но хэшсумма разная. Если скопировать конечную таблицу на винчестер компьютера и открыть её в любом просмотрщике sqlite то вы не увидите там своих таблиц. Мне помог вот такой код

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;
    if (dbExist) {
    } else {
        myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        myDataBase.close();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v("Cannot create database", "Cannot create database1");
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {        
    return m_Context.getDatabasePath(myPath).exists();
}
```

Здесь использовалась `getReadableDatabase` но вообще лучше всегда использовать `getWritableDatabase`

Comment: Спасибо за мнение, но это все не то. Дело не в этом. Сам способ ошибочен изначально(описанный по ссылке). Эта таблица создается автоматически для любой открываемой базы в Андроид и в нее записывается текущая локаль. Правильный способ - это копировать данные сразу в базу в методе onCreate(), а обновлять в onUpgrade()

Comment: признаюсь я и сам не определил до конца природу ошибки "No such table", но вот то что отсутствует именно android_metadata для меня странно потому что даже если она отсутствует в изначальной базе из assets то создаётся при первом же вызове getReadableDatabase/getWritableDatabase. Это факт. Внешний файл парсить не вариант, так как занимает процессорное время, а в моём случае это было бы очень долго. Попробуйте понаставить брейкпойнтов на разных стадиях созданий БД и во время остановок просматривать содержимое БД и вобще её наличие.

Comment: Также посмотрите во это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273300/ioexception-while-reading-from-inputstream/1274766#1274766. Такая ошибка может возникнуть в API < 8. Скорее всего в Desire возникала именно она

Comment: А теперь поспорим:) Процессорное время также занимает побайтовое чтение базы, а читаем мы в память. Я не думаю, что работа с потоками при чтении готовой БД и парсинг json-а, например, уж очень отличаются по времени работы, но во втором случае у вас не будет косяка...пусть висит крутяшка, юзер подождет чутка, зато все стабильно будет работать. Повторюсь, то что описано в статье - бред. Использовать SQLiteOpenHelper нужно как я описал. В любой книге и туториале используется именно такой подход. А Desire был с андроид 2.2.

Comment: Ну признаться я не очень то хотел спорить, но раз уж ... то ок. Вот вам голый факт: БД размером 2.5Мб копируется 1-2 сек, xml размером 745Кб и не очень сложной структурой парсится (и добавляются записи в пустую БД) 30 сек. При этом в конечном счёте в бд есть индексы, в json (или xml) нет. соответственно чтобы быстро осуществлять выборку данных из файла, нужно чтобы его содержимое постоянно висело в памяти. Я так понимаю что вы уже точно определились со своим методом - если так то дальше не имеет смысла спорить. Но я вам всёже советую ещё поковырять способ из той статьи - он реально работает -

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста почту или способ как с вами можно связаться для дальнейшего обсуждения (лимит комментариев исчерпан)

Comment: Я спорить сам не люблю, но чтобы понять, кто прав нужны замеры производительности на практике, а так я очень неуверен, что индексы SQLite что-то дают, если они вообще поддерживаются этой БД.
Я упираюсь так, потому что столько косяков ловил с этим подходом от приложения, которое уже в маркете. Напишите свой пример полностью, ибо то, что Вы вставили все и так есть, только checkDatabase() изначально другой. И еще вопрос: у Вас есть приложение в маркете с большим количеством скачек которое использует данный подход?

Comment: Кроме того в книге от человека, работающего над Андроид в Google, SQLiteOpenHelper используется как описывал я, но я просто добавил парсинг. Я думаю что копировании БД в таком случае, лучше вставлять в метод onCreate(), который вызывается когда система проверяет есть ли база или нет.

Comment: Можно писать на Хабр, если у Вас есть профиль или на alexfromakb@gmail.com(но отвечу с почты не ранее чем около 21-22 по МСК)