# Размещение созданной БД SQLite в проекте под Android

Tags: android, java, sqlite, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Пишу небольшой справочник, в основе которого будет база данных. Файл БД создан на стороне средствами специального ПО. Данный файл нужно подгрузить в приложение Android. Каким образом размещать файл, каков путь для доступа к внедряемой БД, какие методы следует реализовать для обеспечения подключения и дальнейшей работы с данной БД в приложении?

Answer (score 4):

Если ещё не читали, то будет полезна статья на Хабре «[Правильная работа с БД в Android](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/125883/)».

Там же есть ссылка на тему [прикрепления БД](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). Сам давно уже использую этот подход. Меня устраивает.

Обсуждение тонкостей также производилось в вопросе «[Правильная работа с SQLite-базой в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/24403/208074)».

Answer (score -1):

Базу на флешку. В приложении сделать выбор пути к базе.