# Sqlite копирование или экспорт

Tags: android, sqlite

Доброго времени суток.
Нуждаюсь в совете.
Нужно организовать обновление базы данных с помощью обновления приложения через google play, базу данных планируется распространять в ресурсах assets, с одной стороны вроде бы все понятно [пример](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), [пример1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/readydb.php) примеров хватает, но опасаюсь ошибок описных [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24403/java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-sqlite-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-android)
Вижу два варианта решения проблемы:

1. Копировать базу данных, то что описано выше
2. Распространять дамп базы

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы не стал полагаться на дамп БД. Дамп это дамп, его формат толком не описан и не стандартизирован, так что нет гарантии что в каком-нибудь аппарате не будет сбоя при попытке обновления через дамп.

Я бы все таки положил в ассеты xml/json данные, которые при `onUpgrade()` через стандартные средства обновят БД.